# jQuery delay stops other jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout, jmenu

basically i'm having a problem with fading out a div when going back a page.

When fading out without a delay the elements inside the div snap to the bottom of the page and then fade out. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#back").click(function () {
           $("#kimg, #kp, #kp2, #kp3, #jprofile,#rprofile,#sprofile,#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent").fadeOut('slow', function () {
               $("#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                   $("#jmain,#jmenu,#kmain,#kmenu,#rmain,#rmenu,#smain,#smenu").fadeIn('slow', function () {
                   });
               });
           });
       });
   });
```

I thought I could fix this problem with adding delays so that the objects inside the div fadeout followed by the div,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#back").click(function () {
           $("#kimg, #kp, #kp2, #kp3, #jprofile,#rprofile,#sprofile,#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent").fadeOut('slow', function () {
               $("#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent").delay(500)fadeOut('slow', function () {
                   $("#jmain,#jmenu,#kmain,#kmenu,#rmain,#rmenu,#smain,#smenu").delay(600).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                   });
               });
           });
       });
   });
```

However, after doing this, the fading works fine for going back to the previous page but then when you try to click on another page it will not load for about 10 seconds, when it finally does the div appears but then the previous page's image push through and then objects that were supposed to be in the appear below that.

To see the site in its current form, without the delay, you can to it at 
[jkrsproductions.com](http://www.jkrsproductions.com). The best example of the div error can be found by going to the "our people" page and then hitting the back button.

Thank you in advance.

-S

Edit: Thank you for your answers, we fixed all the fadeout problems, however the 10 second delay when going back a page and trying to click on another page still persists. This is the revised code; we took out the middle part after realizing we don't need it thanks to Barmar:

```
$("#back").click(function () {
           $("#kimg, #kp, #kp2, #kp3, #jprofile,#rprofile,#sprofile,#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                   $("#jmain,#jmenu,#kmain,#kmenu,#rmain,#rmenu,#smain,#smenu").delay(700).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                   });

           });
       });
```

Comment: I think you need to set the callback `($(selector).fadeOut(speed,callback);)`

Comment: [look](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

Comment: Ever considered using a common class instead of a thousand ids?

Comment: I assume a missing dot after the `.delay(500)` in the third line is a typo here, and not in the actual code

Comment: The shifting is happening because the fadeIn is happening while some of the old elements are still visible.  The `fadeOut` callback function gets called for each element being faded, not when all the fades have completed; see the jQuery documentation for how to use a promise to do it for all of them. It might work to use z-index to overlay the pages, so they don't have to be shifted around while they're both visible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you calling `.fadeOut()` on the elements `#jcontent,#back,#kcontent,#rcontent,#scontent` when they've already just been faded by the line before that?

Comment: Yes the missing dot after the delay was a typo, as was the repeating elements.

Comment: You should answer on your question and accept that answer if you found solution your self. No answers in questions please